# Find $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n(2n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n(2n+1)}$

I couldn't find any pattern of this series, so that it become solvable.

Can this series be changed in any telescoping series form?
I just need a hint to start.

Comment: Hint: If you start at $n=1$, the final answer should be $2-2\log(2)$

Comment: Hint: use partial fractions to write
$$\frac{1}{n(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{2}{2n+1}$$